How to name a text with a line in the middle: strike-through, struck-through, struck-out, crossed-out, crossed-off or maybe something else?
How to name this text?
(1) a strike-through text
(2) a struck-through text
(3) a struck-out text
(4) a crossed-out text
(5) a crossed-off text
or maybe something else?

Name, or describe?

@TimR I chose "name" because it perfectly translates into my native language. But if it's incorrect, please tell me and I'll replace it with "describe".

Well, I'm not sure which you want to do.  The name for that kind of text decoration, so to speak, is "strike-through" but in a description of text that has been so decorated you could say "A sentence has been crossed out" or "Several words are  struck out". A premodifier (e.g.  "There are some struck out words") is not always a fluent choice when the adjective is formed from a phrasal verb; it would be better to say "There are some words struck out".

I would in general not talk about "a text" of any type in this case. The use of "text" as a count noun usually refers to the entirety of a written work or sample. So you'd only say "a crossed-out text" if all of the words in the entire book (or article, or webpage, or whatever) had been struck through.

it is not entirely clear what you are asking ... using the word text in both the example and in the choices is confusing ... if the example was How to name this abc123?, then would the first choice be a strike-through abc123, or would it still be a strike-through text?

I think you might get the best answer if you give an example sentence with a blank for what you're trying to say

Yes, those are all reasonable, I wouldn't use (1) because it's the wrong tense. And I might well prefer "A word/phrase that has been crossed out/struck through", as it isn't a type of text.

I wouldn't use 'a text', either, about a sample or piece of text.
